# Triple-nested Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, upperbound

I am trying to understand Java Generics and UpperBound Wildcards on more complicated examples.

I have a list of lists of anything that extends a list of any type of object:

```
List<List<? extends List<?>>> veryNestedList;
```

I was thinking whether I the first nested List could actually accept any implementation of ArrayList.

In my thinking:

```
List<? extends ArrayList<?>>
```

should be subType of:

```
List<? extends List<?>>
```

So going this way I have tried:

```
List<List<? extends List<?>>> veryNestedList = new ArrayList<List<? extends ArrayList<?>>>();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

What I need to do instead is:

```
List<? extends List<? extends List<?>>> veryNestedList = new ArrayList<List<? extends ArrayList<?>>>();
```

I'm not really sure whats the reason for this.

@Edit
Now when I look at this:

Is it because even though

```
 List<? extends ArrayList<?>>
```

is subtype

```
 List<? extends List<?>>
```

When we put it into generic type of another list it's no longer covariant?

Comment: List< ? extends ArrayList< ? >> is NOT a subtype of List< ? extends List< ? >>

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265 ?

Comment: `List<? extends ArrayList<?>>` is not a "covariant type" (whatever it is) of `List<? extends ArrayList<?>>`.